# Where statement: isolating matching values in one column based on the attributes of another

Tags: mysql

### ID|Round

1  |   1

2 | 2

3 | 2

4 | 1

1 | 3

4 | 4

New to SQL so please forgive me if I bungle the lexicon. I'm trying to figure out how to specify a where clause so I can isolate all rows with IDs that match IDs occurring in Round 1 (regardless of round). The preferred output would be this:

### ID|Round

1 | 1

4 | 1

1 | 3

4 | 4

ID 1 and 4 occurred in Round 1, so I want all rows that have ID 1 or 4 (and to exclude IDs that didn't occur in Round 1 ,i.e. IDs 2 and 3).

Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to formulate a search that turns up an answer to this problem. Working in MySQL if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from table where id in(select id from table where round = 1
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help, saved me a lot of time and searching.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept it as the answer on the page.